# automatically get links my friends post to Facebook into Instapaper?

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that

I usually use IFTTT for this kind of thing, but it doesn't have the right Facebook triggers: IFTTT has a "new link post by you"; what I want is a "new link post by your friend" trigger.  Does anyone know a workaround?